# Auto start chromecast a website

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am trying to write a simple code just very simple that if a page ie http://domain.com/something.html is brought up in the browser the html page will start chromecast automatically

Is that a valid case or is there any sample code or a place where I can start?
I have my chromecast whitelisted, registered for the dev sdk but all samples I see are to start youtube and stuff

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at our [UX Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ux_guidelines) and [UX Checklist](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist).  Automatic bringup isn't something we support.

Comment: So there is no auto cast function ? I know there is an api call to auto cast a youtube video, isn't there something similar to auto cast a website (html page) ?

Comment: I'm unaware of any auto Cast functionality.